# forced Https RewriteRule .htaccess gives 403 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my .htaccess file for my site. I want to force people to use https for my site so I have added this to my already existing .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

End result:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=news&id=$1
RewriteRule ^home/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=home&user=$1
RewriteRule ^swf/plex-imaging/badge/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ swf/plex-
imaging/badge.php?badge=$1
RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?
url=register&userref=$1
RewriteRule ^newpassword/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?
url=newpassword&key=$1
```

But now I get a 403 error:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by reloading my ssl certificate!

Comment: How do you reload your SSL Certificate? I am also using Let's encrypt for certificate. So, how did you do it? As soon as I add that piece of code and upload the .htaccess file into my server, my whole website goes blank and it says Forbidden. I take it out, my website works again. Any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=news&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^home/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=home&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^swf/plex-imaging/badge/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ swf/plex-imaging/badge.php?badge=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^register/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=register&userref=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^newpassword/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=newpassword&key=$1 [L]
```

I've updated the RewriteRule for your HTTPS redirect so that it sends an HTTP status code of 301 and does a redirect instead of a rewrite. Without the [flag `R=301`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) the server only rewrites the connection as though the user connected via the new URL you gave it (this is how pretty URLs are done). I also added the [`L` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) to signify each rule shouldn't have another rule processed after it.

The extra `RewriteEngine On` was also taken out, however that's probably not the cause of your issue.

The last update I made was to a couple of the RewriteRules, all I did was ensure that they were on the same line since they had been broken up onto two.

You can read more about apache's rewriterule flags [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html).

Comment: Nope, it sadly doesn't work. (Thanks for your help though). I'm going to ask my web host about this. (or do you have an another idea?). Again many thanks for your help.

Comment: Out of curiosity does it complete the https redirect? Do you know if the web server is setup properly for HTTPS? In Apache it usually requires 2 different virtual hosts (one for port 80 and one for 443). If the redirect is completing then that may be your problem.

Comment: I followed my web host guide on how to enable https on my website, so i made a certificate from Let's encrypt and so forth. then i had to add the redirect rule. to force people on https.

Comment: Does the site redirect over to https when you go to it using http? If that's the case then the  htacess is probably working and it's another hosting config issue which you'll probably have to ask your host for help on